# Layout having two layout in it Horizontally Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout. Now i want to use two layout with same details and these two layouts will be inside this layout so that i can show the same layout side by side in a layout 
Here is my xml file please help me on this  :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false" 
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flightLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flightCompany"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="SpiceJet"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flightNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="SG-142" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BOS"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="17:40" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Jan 19" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrivalLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SOF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrivalTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="23:45" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrivalDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Jan 19" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6h45m"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalCost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30,193"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/book" />
    </LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both widths for the sub layouts are `match_parent` so only one will show, `match_parent` is for the main layout and all sublayouts and elements should have `fill_parent` instead, Also because you are using weight you can set the width to `0dp` and the weight will take care of the scaling

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flightLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flightCompany"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="SpiceJet"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flightNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="SG-142" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departLocation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BOS"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="17:40" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Jan 19" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrivalLocation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SOF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrivalTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="23:45" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrivalDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Jan 19" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6h45m"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalCost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30,193"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/book" />
    </LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no i want this complete layout inside a main layout twice side bu side

Comment: but in my device it is not fiting up properly i am using micromax canvas

Comment: Beyond what I've shown, there's not much you can do about the scaling  as the width will vary from device to device. Your only option would be doing something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Comment: I just kinda picked it up as I went along, and using the graphical layout thing in eclipse to drag stuff around then looking at the xml that it generates is good too, though it only really works for relative layouts

Comment: i have to design many layout i am confused how could i do them .Designing for me is complicated .what could i do get away from it.i have just started work in android