# How I can fill an activity programatically with elements

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, fill

my question is not how to fill the screen, actually my question is what is the best way to do this?. I want to fill an activity with a lot of imageviews (small), many images as will fit on each screen (resolution).

What do you think that is the best way to do this?

Example

```
  1 Device               Another Resolution Device
______________    _______________________________________
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
|************|    |*************************************|
______________    _______________________________________
```

I don't know If I explained me well. Thank you.

COMMENT: Each * is a different imageview for example.

Comment: try this[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Comment: Thanks Jony, I'll read it, with the hope that this can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create drawable/app_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/small_pattern_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Refer this background.

Comment: If I do this, how I can differentiate each image?? This is why I asked  by the "programmatically" way, to do this differentiation more easy.