# editText.setTextSize does not work sometimes

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I use custom font:

```
myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
```

Depending on screen size I calculate font size as mySize variable. I use

```
editText.setTypeface(myTypeface);
editText.setTextSize(mySize);
```

Size is correct on 1024*600, 640*480 devices,
but text height is big on 800*480 device.
So calculated mySize does not work.
It shows bigger text.
I suspect that I can use only certain sizes such as 10,14,20,25,etc
And calculated mySize is not supported sometimes.
But I don't know which sizes are available for my font.
So what should I do to show my page on different devices correctly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is `mySize` calculated dynamically based on screen size or is it a constant?

By default `setTextSize` sets the size in `px` so will appear different on different screen densities.

To use density-independent scalable pixels (`sp`) you should use `editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP ,mySize);`

Comment: mySize is px and depends on screen size. I tryed to use the same proportions on any screen. Okay, thanks, I will try your approach

Comment: You approach looks okay on emulator and 1024*720, but text is too big again on 800*480 device. Strange, that emulator settings is also 800*480 and the performance is okay there.

Comment: You might need to create resource folders for the different screen sizes you support and a dimens.xml with a hardcoded text size to each. You can use that value in your code for setting a bigger text size for tablets etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. But I could not understand the idea and how to use it programmatically. I tryed to use mySize=20 everywhere as SP as you said. But the text is big on small resolutions

Comment: My emulator and device have the same 800*480 (my app recognized correctly), but on device the height of text is much bigger.