# Font size in XML for Android Wear resolutions

Tags: android

How can I have different xml font sizes for different Android Wear Watches?
Currently there are 280/320/360/400/480 resolution watches. I adjust my fonts programmatically  after I detect the screen size with onSurfaceChanged();
Can I have different .xml for different resolution and how should I define it? It will be a lot more better solution and it will cut my code a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes ?

Comment: Yes, but how does the layout sizes relate to the screen resolution of the wear devices?