# Different strings for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-resources, android-screen-support

I have two devices:
first is 320x480px 3.5"
second is 540x960px 5.3"

I want the first one to display the shorter string so I add :

`values-ldpi/strings.xml`

`values-normal-mdpi/strings.xml`

But the second device is displaying modified string anyway, however it is clearly not normal size and a little closer to the hdpi range. Why is it happening?

Edit:

All the strings are located in values/strings.xml.
For the "small"(first) device I need to override some strings to be a little shorter, but the second device should use default, so I put overridden strings into
`values-ldpi/strings.xml`
`values-normal-mdpi/strings.xml`
but the second device picks up overriden strings. Why?
here are devices parameters

[image: first device][image]

Comment: download this app on both devices to check what the system reports about them https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.qbus.sizemeup

Comment: can take a look at this post: it uses sp metric for text size for different screen devices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Comment: Budius, check out my edit.

Comment: rafsanahmad007, I don't need to resize characters, I need different strings for these devices.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using DPIs to discriminate device screens, rather use `small`, `normal`, `large`, etc. So your `res` folders will include:

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-small/strings.xml
res/values-normal/strings.xml
res/values-large/strings.xml
res/values-xlarge/strings.xml
```

Give this a try and let us know if it helps.

Comment: That doesn't help, both devices are in "normal" range