# Setting textsize of a button dynamically

Tags: android

I have been trying to set the textsize of the text of a button in my code but the problem is that the text appears normal on my Galaxy tab s2 (I am using this device for testing) but when I open the app on my xperia MP4 dual, the text gets cramped and the text (text is "CHOSEN") splits into two lines (CHOS in one, and EN in the other). I have added the supports screens block in my manifest file but it doesn't work. Moreover, I read something about creating different dimens.xml folders for each screen size (Link: [Text size and different android screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes)), but I am confused as to how to use them in my code so that the code dynamically adjusts the textsize.

Comment: Try to share some of your code for a better understanding of the problem. Or maybe a test example to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

create values folder for different screens

```
res/values/dimens.xml(default)
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320 and nearer resolution)
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480 and nearer resolution)
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD, etc) 
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml (1080x1920 - Samsung S4, HTC one, etc)
res/values-large/dimens.xml  (480x800)
res/values-large-mdpi/dimens.xml (600x1024)
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml  (600x1024)
res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml  (800x1280)
res/values-xlarge-xhdpi/dimens.xml (2560x1600 - Nexus 10")
res/values-large-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (1200x1920 - Nexus 7"(latest))
```

Or you can do that by putting

```
View.setTextSize(size in px);
```

In onCreate method
you can also set text size as a function of display size by

```
Display d=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int w=d.getWidth();
int h=d.getHeight();
View.setTextSize(Math.sqrt(w*w+h*h)/(edit here));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but could  you please explain the last line of code??(Math.sqrt(w*w+h*h)/(edit here))

Comment: I am calculating the length of diagonal of screen and then setting the textsize according to that

Comment: This will avoid text from getting out of bounds of the view

Comment: Is the View referring to the class 'View' or the buttonview? And whats 'edit here'?

Comment: You can use any View(Button,EditText,TextView) there and you have to put a number in place of edit here like if you find (diagonal length/50) as the best fit then put 50 at the place of edit here

Comment: So this display class will get me the length of the diagonal of any view i want ,like text button etc.?

Comment: Display class is not returning the length of view it is returning the length of display like if your screen resolution is 1600×2560 then h will be 1600 in landscape mode and 2560 in portrait mode

Comment: If you found my answer helpful can you please up vote my answer as I'm blocked for asking questions because of too many negative votes on my silly questions

Comment: Oh ok alright understood. Thanks alot fr the help!!

Comment: I did do that but it won't publicly be shown since i am new to stackoverflow. And could u do the same fr my question since i have had a similar experience XP xD

Comment: Oh I'm also new to this  okay leave it!