# Is there any way to create a single xml or layout file for the application to work on different phones and tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an android application that should be supported for both phones and tablets. I found a way to create multiple layout files for each size, but I don't want to do it. Is there any way to do it through programming or some other way.

Comment: Which way do you try to do this?

Comment: yes you will achive this by using proper .xml design.

Comment: use dimen files with different size density and write suitable dimensions for your xml for different resolution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes check this link with the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to android and unable to do it.
Sagar Aghara : Can you elaborate your answer please.?

Comment: Ankush Bisht : I already mentioned, Is there any other way I can do it without creating individual files for different dimensions.

Comment: @Rider..i think you have to go in Developer site for Android.you can collect more Knowledge from there...yes also check below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the width and height to certain dp values. Instead give it as `match_parent` or `wrap_content`.
Also, try to include the following in manifest file.

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you Meena.
I have one more doubt. My layout is not displayed properly in tablet as it gets displayed in phone. What should I do to get the proper layout?

Comment: And also I want my app to work only in portrait, not landscape. How can I do that.?

Comment: In manifest,    <activity
            android:name=".YourActivityName"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Comment: Hey Meena,
As asked by you, I added my xml file. Can you please explain me what edits I should make to get proper layout in phone and tablets.

Comment: can you attach the screenshots of the design page taken from phone and tablet.

Comment: Meena I added the images.

Comment: I want it to be displayed like its getting displayed in phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put height and width match parent and give weight ti every content then it will render in every screen.