# text ellipsize behavior in android version < 6.0

Tags: android, textview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.4-kitkat

I have below layout in my `xml` which will contain 3 `TextView` and they are aligned `left`, `centre` and `right` respectively.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="@string/contact"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/colon"
            android:id="@+id/colonRow1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrimaryContact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/colonRow3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/colonRow3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Joe SmithMartinWilliamCathcsdsdsdadas"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem I am facing now is that, the `ellipsize` doesn't go well or work as expected with android device version < 6.0. I mean for device with `Marshmallow` version, the `ellipsize` is breaking the text once max width is reached, but for devices having `lollipop` or `kitkat` version, may be lower too, <strike>the `ellipsize` breaks down after **space** in text and displays `ellipses`</strike>, it does not break for long text.

Here is how it looks in android version less than `Marshmallow`:

Consider the name is **FName LName**

> Contact   : FName...

Here is how it looks in android version greater than `Marshmallow`:

> Contact   : FName LNa...

Is this a bug in lower versions or expected behavior. Or is there any other way to do this? I would like to have the `Marshmallow`version text in all the devices. Anyway I can achieve this?

**Update**

Turns out, my assumption was wrong after @Charu's comment. It actually hides out for long text in device version < `Marshmallow`. How can I come over this?

Right now I've been using below code, but that doesn't scale up when we check with different devices with different screen size. I've attached screenshots for reference.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.M && name.length()>20)
     name=name.substring(0,20)+"...";
else
     txtPrimaryContact.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

---

**>=Marshmallow device**

[image: Marshmallow device]

---

**< Marshmallow device [Kitkat to be specific but tested in Lollipop too]**

---

[image: Lower than Marshmallow]

Comment: post screenshots if possible

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao *the ellipsize breaks down after space in text and displays ellipses* are you sure just and `F (space) Name` and see if it goes like `F...` I don't think so

Comment: Its depend on space in TextView and TextSize with respect t your Device resolution .

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android/32861248#32861248

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao well to get over with this thing you might wish to have something like this , keep N number of chars anyway and after that ... like you did, for any screen using auto resize text view how about that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981272/textview-getting-cut-in-some-resolutions your issue is something related with the device screen size,dpi i guess, not with the OS version

Comment: @Charuක Yes, it is kind of both.. `sdp` would much fit here.. Let me check how I can get work-around for this.. But am still wondering why it breaks for long character words and why doesn't behave like Marshmallow.. Anyways.. Thanks for your time and suggestion buddy.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might tell me that `android:singleLine="true"` is kind of deprecated that's why you used `android:maxLines="1"` but trust me adding this  `android:singleLine="true"` to your `textView` should fix the issue!

Comment: Buddy.. You are awesome.. This simple thing was blocking me all the day.. I don't know why they don't specify this simple thing when they can identify, what's the minimum version selected for application.. Thank you, Thank you and Thank you so much.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks much once again.. I just can't thank you enough.. :) You don't know how huge headache was this for me.. :)

Comment: Thanks mate, this solved my issue, where ellipsize didn't work when talkback was activated on Android 4.4!