# Handling Margin Top with Multiple Screens

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio and to developing a native android application. No i've done my splashscreen for the application. but i'm using "dp" attribute for positioning and sizing. But when i run the application on different screens(i.e phone vs tablet). there was an attribute marginTop that i set with 400dp but the element's position is different on the phone rather than the tablet.

What's the correct form to use when positioning and resizing??.. isn't dp supposed to handle this?!

here's my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#181c2c">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
    android:id="@+id/avi"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/AVLoadingIndicatorView"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
    app:indicatorColor="#1ed760"
/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981272/textview-getting-cut-in-some-resolutions/42019572#42019572 see it url

Comment: not working roma

Comment: check this library? https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: not working as expected, i'm trying nexus 5 vs nexus 10(tablet) and both viewing different positions.

Comment: i think it works with well-known tags only? , as i'm using a thirdparty xml tag and it doesn't work well, however when i tried the attached example everything works perfectly fine. I mean by third party tags the second xml tag in the attached code above.

Comment: Third partly library classes can define their own layout parameters within the Java code. That's probably your error