# Is lable <font size="15"></font> in string.xml accords with compatibility?

Tags: android, xml, fonts

To set hintSize of EditText, I set font size in string.xml,like this:

```
<string name="hello_world"><font size="15">Hello world!</font></string>
```

```
<EditText>
 android:hint="@string/hello_word"
</EditText>
```

It works, while I confuse if it works fine on different devices with different screens?

Comment: You should ref this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right way to use

string.xml

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

style xml

```
<style name="style">
    <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/standout_text</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

> use that style on `TextView`

Comment: Can it makes the textSize and hintSize different, of EditText?