# How to handle different font sizes of text?

Tags: android, performance, font-size

This is my issue.

All text size in my app screen looks fine when my user chooses font size to be small from android

 **settings-->display -->Text size --> small**
[image: Image containing when my font size is small]

same app screen looks messy when my user chooses font size to be large from android

 **settings-->display -->Text size --> Large**
[image: Image containing when my font size is large]

How to make my app screens look better in all font sizes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/unknown_contact"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voicemailcontactname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Unknown"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="calibri"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_font"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/voicemailcontactpic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voicemailcontactnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/voicemailcontactname"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/voicemailcontactname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/voicemailcontactname"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="1234"
        android:fontFamily="calibri"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_font"
        android:textSize="12sp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voicemaildownloadsize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/voicemaildownload"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/voicemaildownload"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:text="122kb"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="calibri"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_font"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voicemailrecievedtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/voicemaildownload"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/voicemaildownload"
        android:layout_below="@+id/voicemailcontactname"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:text="12:01 PM"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="calibri"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_font"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat"
        />

        <com.nexge.nexgetalkclass5.app.voicemail.CircularProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/voice_mail_file_download_Progress"
            style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Holo.CircularProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/voicemaildownload"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/voicemailcontactpic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/voicemail_download"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/voicemail_player_layout"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/voicemail_player_play_btn"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/media_player_play"

    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/voicemail_player_pause_btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/media_player_pause"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/voicemail_player_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/voicemail_player_play_btn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/voicemail_player_play_btn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/voicemail_player_play_btn"
    android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/voicemail_file_start_time_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/voicemail_player_seekbar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/voicemail_player_seekbar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/voicemail_player_seekbar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

    android:fontFamily="calibri"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/voicemail_file_end_time_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="calibri"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/voicemail_player_seekbar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/voicemail_player_seekbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/voicemail_player_seekbar"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share your layout.xml with question

Comment: are you usinfg sp or dp for setting text size?

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari im using sp for setting textsize in layout

Comment: Please add your layout xml file

Comment: Just use dp instead of sp. It will never change your text again

Comment: @Jeeva if you are using "sp" then you need to handle for all the screens sizes, beacuse if we use use "sp" and we check the app after setting larger font so it disturbs the UI because we haven't handle that as per diffrent screen sizes and styles, better you should use "dp" so your text would be same even after you change the font size from settings.

Comment: what is your minimum api level?

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari but android specifically say that use sp for font size so android handles that font size in all UI screen density??

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan 16

Comment: @Jeeva yes basically it is standard way to use of "sp" but if you are not using styles for different different screen sizes, and you use "sp" so , after changing the settings font it will adopt the font size of your settings , so better solution is use "dp" or handle all screens sizes with the help of styles.

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari how to handle all screen sizes with help of styles can u give a link ??

Comment: @Jeeva , i wrote line in my answer . hopefully it will adjust font size according to screen size

Comment: @Jeeva check this link it will help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883641/2919483

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari it seems to be a tooooooooooo lonnnnnnngggg road.but i need short one

Comment: @Jeeva i gave you short solution as well, use dp insted sp

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari hope it works

Comment: @Jeeva try and check :)

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari when user changes it affects images sizes also so mayb longg road.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use textsize, Use textAppearance for fontSize